# C# How to create a generic List of KeyValuePair

Tags: c#, list, generics, httpclient, keyvaluepair

I have created a list of KeyValuePair to populate the content as the data for the HttpClient.

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("email", email));
keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password));
keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("plan_id", planId));

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues);
```

But later I found I have to send a int value as the plan_id. How can change the above list to accept KeyValuePair. Or is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Ultimately everything in HTTP is sent as an ASCII string, so why not just call `planId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`?

Comment: I am calling an external API. When I send a string value for the plan id I am getting a Bad Request. But with a int value it is getting success.

Comment: Is it possible to create generic list as follow in java. List<KeyValuePair<string, T>> keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, T>>();

Comment: Well `FormUrlEncodedContent` will only accept an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> nameValueCollection` so unless you encode your content differently that's what you will have to do and as @Dai mentioned, convert your integer to its string representation.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to create a [KeyValuePair](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) list, you should create Dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string,string>();
dic.Add("email", email);
dic.Add("password", password);
dic.Add("plan_id", planId.ToString());
```

Comment: Here what need to create is something like this. Like generic ArrayList in java. List<KeyValuePair<string, T>> keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, T>>();

Comment: This solution does not allow duplicates!

Answer (score 4):

Use `KeyValuePair<string, object>` to put values and **create** or **convert** the list to `KeyValuePair<string, string>` when to use FormUrlEncodedContent

## Creating a new list

```cs
List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();

keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("email", "asdasd"));
keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("password", "1131"));
keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("plan_id", 123));
keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("other_field", null));

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues.Select(s => 
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>(s.Key, s.Value != null ? s.ToString() : null)
));
```

## Convert list

```cs
public static KeyValuePair<string, string> ConvertRules(KeyValuePair<string, object> kv)
{
    return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(kv.Key, kv.Value != null ? kv.ToString() : null);
}

static Task Main(string[] args) 
{
    List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();

    keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("email", "asdasd"));
    keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("password", "1131"));
    keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("plan_id", 123));
    keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("other_field", null));

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues.ConvertAll(ConvertRules)));
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>`,  instead of `Dictionary<string, string>`.   use planId.ToString().